# New line within CSV column causing issue

Tags: c#, csv, c#-4.0

I have a large csv file which has millions of rows. The sample csv lines are

```
CODE,COMPANY NAME, DATE, ACTION
A,My Name , LLC,2018-01-28,BUY
B,Your Name , LLC,2018-01-25,SELL
C,
All Name , LLC,2018-01-21,SELL
D,World Name , LLC,2018-01-20,BUY
```

Row C has new line, but actually this is same record. I want to remove new line character from the csv line within cell\field\column.

I tired `\r\n`, `Envirnment.NewLine` and many other things, but could not make it work.

Here is my code..

```
 private DataTable CSToDataTable(string csvfile)
    {
        Int64 row = 0;
        try
        {

            string CSVFilePathName = csvfile; //@"C:\test.csv";
            string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
            string[] Fields;
            Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
            for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
                dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToLower(), typeof(string));
            DataRow Row;
            for (row = 1; row < Lines.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                Fields = Lines[row].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                Row = dt.NewRow();
                //Console.WriteLine(row);
                for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                {
                    Row[f] = Fields[f];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(Row);
                if (row == 190063)
                {
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

How can I remove new line character and read the row correctly? I don't want to skip the such rows as per the business requirement.

Comment: Looks like you are removing the newline from the file path and not the actual document.  You likely want to only remove the newline when the line ends in a `,`, otherwise you will flatten the whole file

Comment: This is bad data. If you're gonna have line breaks in csv records, you need the text fields for those records enclosed in quotes. Also, if you have millions of rows, you probably want `File.ReadLines()` rather than `File.ReadAllLines()`. You _definitely_ want to get away from using the `.Split()` function for parsing a line. There are so many edge cases where it fails.

Comment: Can you actually _reliable detect_ these lines through some automated way? Because, if not, then this is not your problem but the problem of whoever generates the faulty csv. As Joel Coehoorn said, csv has certain rules, and they're not hard. Also note that .Net has an actual csv parser, called `TextFieldParser`, in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CSV file is not in valid format. In order to parse and load them successfully, you will have to sanitize them. Couple of issues

1. COMPANY NAME column contains field separator in it. Fix them by
   surrounding quotes.
2. New line in CSV value - This can be fixed by combining adjacent rows as one.

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/), you can sanitize and load your large file as below

```
string csv = @"CODE,COMPANY NAME, DATE, ACTION
A,My Name , LLC,2018-01-28,BUY
B,Your Name , LLC,2018-01-25,SELL
C,
All Name , LLC,2018-01-21,SELL
D,World Name , LLC,2018-01-20,BUY";

string bufferLine = null;
var reader = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv)
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    .Setup(s => s.BeforeRecordLoad += (o, e) =>
    {
        string line = (string)e.Source;
        string[] tokens = line.Split(",");

        if (tokens.Length == 5)
        {
            //Fix the second and third value with quotes
            e.Source = @"{0},""{1},{2}"",{3}, {4}".FormatString(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4]);
        }
        else
        {
            //Fix the breaking lines, assume that some csv lines broken into max 2 lines
            if (bufferLine == null)
            {
                bufferLine = line;
                e.Skip = true;
            }
            else
            {
                line = bufferLine + line;
                tokens = line.Split(",");
                e.Source = @"{0},""{1},{2}"",{3}, {4}".FormatString(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4]);
                line = null;
            }
        }
    });

foreach (var rec in reader)
    Console.WriteLine(rec.Dump());

//Careful to load millions rows into DataTable
//var dt = reader.AsDataTable();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made it clear what are the possible criteria an unwanted new line could appear in the file. So assuming that a 'proper' line in the CSV file does NOT end with a comma, and if one ends with a comma that means that it's not a properly formatted line, you could do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"CSVFile.csv";

    List<CSVData> data = new List<CSVData>();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            sr.ReadLine();  // Header
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (line.EndsWith(","))
                {
                    line += sr.ReadLine();
                }
                var items = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                data.Add(new CSVData() { CODE = items[0], NAME = items[1], COMPANY = items[2], DATE = items[3], ACTION = items[4] });
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class CSVData
{
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string COMPANY { get; set; }
    public string DATE { get; set; }
    public string ACTION { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously there's a lot of error handling to be done here (for example, when creating a new `CSVData` object make sure your `items` contain all the data you want), but I think this is the start you need.